# How to measure the values for when to scale web app aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices

I am trying to discover the best way to measure when my webapp should scale in amazon aws.

The app consists of a microservices backend **(spring-boot)** + **angular** frontend, for those two parts, how should i go about testing the limits of the EC2 instances?

- What is the max number of simultaneous requests my frontend can take in a single instance ?
- How many connections with the backend can be made ?
- What EC2 instance will be best for each case ?

*Any direction in **how to measure** those values will be helpful.*

*The app will be hit "very hard" (250k visitors per day)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct answer to this. You need to do your own testing.

You could use [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) as an example of a web application testing framework.

And for a backend database, there are tools like [YCSB](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB), but your database might have its benchmarking tests.

CPUs, cores, memory, etc all take a factor, but this largely depends on how your code is written. For example, a JVM-based process will take more resources than one written in Golang (and be slower overall, but that is a separate point).

AWS Cloudwatch can monitor a lot of system-level properties, but monitoring the Java heap is also critical

If you really want to test scalability, run your app in EKS or Fargate or even as a Serverless Lambda rather than a static EC2 box.

You'll definitely want at least two instances in two availability zones for fault tolerance, and you should put a load balancer in front of your apps to control that traffic